# PhpStorm database prefix in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpstorm

I am using PhpStorm for a couple of weeks and I want to ask if it is possible to set it somehow to allow dynamic SQL queries.

I am using queries such as

```
SELECT `gid` FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "groups`"
```

and `DB_PREFIX` is all the time the same. Nothing is changing. Is it possible to set it up somehow so it will normally works? Because at this point it is transforming that query to

```
SELECT `gid` FROM `${DB_PREFIX}groups`
```

and showing me warning that row `gid` does not exists.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's not possible to do that.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-26986 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.

ATM this ticket is not scheduled for any specific future version (plus it currently has no votes).

---

Related ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-16205